# What is the table design for DBCC History of the command DBCC CheckDB on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, datatypes, dbcc-checkdb

I cannot find anything other than a SQL Server 2017 table structure which lists [RepairLevel] as an int, which in SQL Server 2019 it isn't, it's a string of sorts, if I set it to varchar(7000), the same as MessageText then it works, but can anyone tell me the exact datatype of the entire table? An official source would be great.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE #errormsgs
(
    [Error]       int NULL,
    [Level]       int NULL,
    [State]       int NULL,
    [MessageText] varchar(7000) NULL,
    [RepairLevel] varchar(7000) NULL,
    [Status]      int NULL,
    [Dbid]        int NULL,
    [DbFragId]    int NULL,
    [ObjectId]    int NULL,
    [IndexId]     int NULL,
    [PartitionId] int NULL,
    [AllocUnitId] int NULL,
    [RidDbId]     int NULL,
    [RidPruId]    int NULL,
    [File]        int NULL,
    [Page]        int NULL,
    [Slot]        int NULL,
    [RefDbId]     int NULL,
    [RefPruId]    int NULL,
    [RefFile]     int NULL,
    [RefPage]     int NULL,
    [RefSlot]     int NULL,
    [Allocation]  int NULL,
)
```

To populate I use

```
dbcc checkdb (DBName) with no_infomsgs,all_errormsgs,tableresults
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RepairLevel` is `nvarchar(22)` according to `GetSchemaTable` returned by this PS script. I see the same on SQL Server 2012 and later versions.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=MySQL2019Server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (tempdb) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS,TABLERESULTS", $connection)
$connection.Open()
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
$schemaTable = $reader.GetSchemaTable()
$reader.Close()
$connection.Close()
$schemaTable | Select-Object ColumnName, DataTypeName, ColumnSize | Out-Host
```

SQL 2019 Results:

```
ColumnName  DataTypeName ColumnSize
----------  ------------ ----------
Error       int                   4
Level       int                   4
State       int                   4
MessageText nvarchar           2048
RepairLevel nvarchar             22
Status      int                   4
DbId        int                   4
DbFragId    int                   4
ObjectId    int                   4
IndexId     int                   4
PartitionId bigint                8
AllocUnitId bigint                8
RidDbId     smallint              2
RidPruId    smallint              2
File        smallint              2
Page        int                   4
Slot        int                   4
RefDbId     smallint              2
RefPruId    smallint              2
RefFile     smallint              2
RefPage     int                   4
RefSlot     int                   4
Allocation  smallint              2
```

The `TABLERESULTS` option does not seem to be documented for `DBCC CHECKDB` so use at your own risk.

Comment: Perfect thank you... Yes it is strange that tableresults isn't documented, "this option has been implemented for most of the DBCC statements in versions SQL 2000 and above." https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2325/capture-and-store-sql-server-database-integrity-history-using-dbcc-checkdb/ so hopefully It'll be around for a while, maybe one day they will document it!

Comment: @PaulZahra, true, `TABLERESULTS` might get documented at some point for the `DBCC` commands that support it. I added the caution on using undocumented behavior to save the trouble of a support call if it disappears in a future version or CU, albeit unlikely that will happen.